# How to center align R generated plots in Rmarkdown with output = Reveal.js (in RStudio)?

Tags: plot, rstudio, r-markdown, reveal.js

I build a reveal.js presentation in RStudio

````
# In the morning

## Gettin up

```{r plot.show1, echo=FALSE}
p1.ly

```
````

This plot has been generated with plot.ly but any plot behaves the same way: it is (horizontally) left aligned on the slide. I would like to center it.

How should I code that directly or via css?

Comment: I cannot confirm to observe the behavior for base plots. For plotly plots you can try adding `<style> div[id*="htmlwidget"] { margin: auto; } </style>` to your document.

Answer (score 0):

```
output:
  revealjs::revealjs_presentation:
    center: true
```

or try this answer https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/issues/1897#issuecomment-301130888